# Postgres between dates does not select the right dates

Tags: postgresql, between

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(create_user_id)::int AS y, 
   x
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        create_user_id, create_time::abstime::date AS x
    FROM 
        table1 AS s
    WHERE
    (
        create_user_id = 16
        OR
        update_user_id = 16
    )
    AND
    (
        CASE WHEN create_user_id = 16 THEN 
                TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + create_time * INTERVAL '1 second'
                BETWEEN 
                    '2015-03-09'
                AND
                    '2016-03-09'
             WHEN update_user_id = 16 THEN 
                TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + update_time * INTERVAL '1 second'
                BETWEEN 
                    '2015-03-09'
                AND
                    '2016-03-09'
        END
    )
) AS res
GROUP BY x ORDER BY x
```

**Output**

```
{
 235;"2014-11-29"
 48;"2014-12-11"
  8;"2014-12-12"
 55;"2014-12-13"
  8;"2014-12-16"
 49;"2014-12-17"
  9;"2014-12-18"
 13;"2014-12-19"
 21;"2014-12-21"
 18;"2016-02-22"
 29;"2016-02-23"
  4;"2016-02-27"
 21;"2016-02-28"
}
```

**First version was**

```
SELECT 
 COUNT(create_user_id)::int AS y, 
 x
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        create_user_id, create_time::abstime::date AS x
    FROM 
        table1 AS s
    WHERE
    (
        create_user_id = 16
        OR
        update_user_id = 16
    )
    AND
    (
        CASE WHEN create_user_id = 16 THEN 
                create_time
                BETWEEN 
                    1449612000
                AND
                    1457474400 
             WHEN update_user_id = 16 THEN 
                update_time
                BETWEEN 
                    1449612000
                AND
                    1457474400 
        END
    )
) AS res
GROUP BY x ORDER BY x
```

My question is why the list starts with `2014-11-29` and how I can fix it. I have tried different data formats like `09.03.2015`.

If I remove `WHEN update_user_id = 16.....AND 1457474400` then it works like it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe you just got in a bit too deep with your `WHERE` statement. It could simply be:

```
SELECT COUNT(create_user_id)::INT AS y,
    x
FROM (
    SELECT create_user_id,
        create_time::abstime::DATE AS x
    FROM table1 AS s
    WHERE (
            create_user_id = 16
            AND TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + create_time * INTERVAL '1 second' BETWEEN '2015-03-09'
                AND '2016-03-09'
            )
        OR (
            update_user_id = 16
            AND TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + update_time * INTERVAL '1 second' BETWEEN '2015-03-09'
                AND '2016-03-09'
            )
    ) AS res
GROUP BY x
ORDER BY x
```

Seems like this could be simplified since the subquery isn't really needed:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(create_user_id)::INT AS y,
    create_time::abstime::DATE AS x 
FROM table1 AS s
WHERE (
        create_user_id = 16
        AND TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + create_time * INTERVAL '1 second' BETWEEN '2015-03-09'
            AND '2016-03-09'
        )
    OR (
        update_user_id = 16
        AND TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + update_time * INTERVAL '1 second' BETWEEN '2015-03-09'
            AND '2016-03-09'
            )       
GROUP BY x
ORDER BY x
```

But perhaps there is more going on in your real query.